# Retrieving a public spreadsheet document with cfhttp

Tags: coldfusion, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have an application that currently retrieves a google spreadsheet in excel format and saves the xls file to the file system. It is using the ColdFusion google Api wrapper on riaforge, http://cfgoogle.riaforge.org/.

The wrapper is authenticating with a google account and then using cfhttp to download the file in binary format. The url to retrieve the document looks like the following. 
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=#urlEncodedFormat(arguments.id)#&fmcmd=#spreadSheetFormat(arguments.format)#

I would like to change the behavior of the app so that it downloads the document directly from a publicly shared document url, but if I use the public document url I end up with an xls file that tells me that my browser does not meet the minimum requirements, so I'm being served the web based view. If I use the same url format that the google docs api wrapper uses then I need to authenticate even though I pass the id of the public document.

I've searched the Google api docs, but I've been unable to find the proper url format to request the public document so that I can directly download the spreadsheet in binary format using cfhttp? What is the format that I need to download a public spreadsheet in xls format without authenticating using cffhttp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to authenticate using Ray's Google API cfc on riaforge. Once authenticated with my own account I could pass the id of a public spreadsheet to the download function of the google cfc and I'm able to download the spreadsheet as xls file. I was not able to find a way to download it without authenticating, but this method will keep the end users from having to authenticate with their account.

Answer (score 1):

Google is most likely reading the "user_agent" variable of the request. In CF this variable is something with coldfusion or java in it by default. Try adding the "useragent" attribute to the cfhttp request and use something common - like "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)".

Comment: I gave this a try and the spreadsheet that I end up with is what I'm assuming is a web response asking for me to authenticate, but if I past the url into an actual browser the public spreadsheet is shown without me being authenticated to google. I'm unsure as to why it would behave differently between executing the url in a browser and by cfhttp?

Comment: There is probably more to it then. I would use Firebug to examine the raw request being sent to google from FF (a request that succeeds) and then see if there are other variables or headers or cookies involved. It's likely going to be trial and error :)

Comment: It seems that it may no longer be possible to download a spreadsheet without authenticating? That could be the true question, does anyone know the url format needed to download a public google spreadsheet without authenticating.

Comment: You might try Ray's Google API cfc - perhaps he has an authentication method. http://cfgoogle.riaforge.org/. Actually - he definitely does have an authentication method.

Comment: I've actually been using Ray's Google API cfc in the application for some time, but was hoping to be able to pull the spreadsheet without authenticating the user. I don't want to store their Google account info, or require them to pass it during the process. The app is importing data from the spreadsheet and I was hoping that I could have the user store the public url value of the spreadsheet in their account and then use that url to pull data from the spreadsheet. I'm just not able to figure out how to get the spreadsheet with cfhttp, without authenticating first, even with a public document.